# Nvidia X server Xorg file disables second monitor option

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, graphics, xorg

I changed forced full composition option to checked to solve screen tearing problem. But if i change this setting, nvidia x serrver generates xorg.conf file and this file disables my second monitor. if i delete xorg and reboot everything solved without force composition. now attached xorg information is forced composition checked and second montior does not recognized. Asus is my external monitor and my built in monitor is hp pavilion 1bv33ea laptops monitor -> this goes right after creating xconf. So how can i add my other monitor to this xconf file manually ?

before force composition checked and there is no xorg file in /etc/X11

[image]

after force composition checked and there is xorg file in /etc/X11
[image]

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 440.82

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "AUS ASUS VP228"
    HorizSync       24.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     48.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 960M"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "1920x1080_75 +1920+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: You don't need to generate xorg.conf file. Remove it. You can enable the composition by adding a command to Startup  Applications instead.

Comment: actually command options also needs to be prepared for 2 monitors. but i could not do it. if you have it please share with me. i found an article about multiple monitors xorg file preperation but couldnt do it: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Troubleshooting#Avoid_screen_tearing